# Extract a recurring and moving text in a tag

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I'm trying to crawl a website (dailystormer) for research purpose and I met a difficulty.

This is my code in python:

```
obj.url = url
opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
response = opener.open(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
article = soup.find("div", { "class" : "entry" })
paragraphs = article.findAll("p")
date = soup.find("time", style=False)
if not date:
   print("Date problem")
   obj.date = datetime.datetime.strptime('June 23, 1912', '%B %d, %Y').strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
else:
   obj.date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date.text.strip(), '%B %d, %Y').strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

The difficulty is concerning the date of publication of the article. In some articles there is a tag `time` but in most of the old article there is no such tag.
So I tried to retrieve the date directly from the text but it may vary, sometimes the date header of the article is like that:

```
<p>July 11, 2013<br/>
<strong>Daily Stormer</strong><br/>
Andrew Anglin</p>
```

or

```
<p>Andrew Anglin<br/>
<strong>Daily Stormer</strong><br/>
July 11, 2013</p>
```

or

```
<p>Andrew Anglin<br/>
<strong>July 11, 2013</strong><br/>
Daily Stormer</p>
```

And sometimes the date is even not here. You can directly see some examples:

[One format](http://www.dailystormer.com/rat-jew-andrew-garfield-says-spider-man-should-engage-in-interracial-bisexuality/)

[Another format](http://www.dailystormer.com/italy-fights-back-bananas-thrown-at-black-minister-during-speech/)

How can I for every example retrieve only the date or nothing if the date is not present?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your examples, I assume the date will always appear in the same format: `"July 11, 2013"`.

Knowing this, you can combine regular expressions with `datetime` module:

```
import re
import datetime

match = re.search(r'>([a-zA-Z].+ \d.+)<\/', text)
date = datetime.strptime(match.group(), '%B %d, %Y').date()
```

**Edit:**
I'm pretty sure the regular expression I used can be simplified, I let finding a better solution to you.

Comment: `r'\w+ \d+, \d+'` might be a simpler regex (assume you only search the text of the first instance of `<p>` in the article.

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = '<p>July 11, 2013<br/><strong>Daily Stormer</strong><br/>Andrew Anglin</p>'; 
var matches = str.match(/>\S{3,} \d{2}, \d{4}/);

var date = '';
if(matches)
{
    date = matches[0].substring(1);
}
console.log('Published date: ',date);
```

Comment: I don't know python so i tried to give you idea in java script I hope this will help you..